# iterating through json getting empty value

Tags: arrays, json

Not able to push values out. Please help!!

```js
function pullJSON(data) {
 var url="https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/subcategories/?event_status=live&token=XXXXXXXXXXX&page_count=4"; // Paste your JSON URL here
  
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
 var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dict = JSON.stringify(data);
  //Logger.log(dict);
   var keys = [];
  for(var k in dict) keys.push(k+':'+dict[k]);
  Logger.log(keys);
  
}
```

Here is the result: [17-03-29 11:41:19:033 EDT] []

[JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxZPl.png)

Comment: function pullJSON(data) {
 var url="https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/subcategories/?event_status=live&token=6JG56LQIQCMFCKVI6EXT&page_count=4"; // Paste your JSON URL here
  
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
 var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dict = JSON.stringify(data);
 rows=[];
     for (i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
    data = dict[i];
        Logger.log(data);
   //rows.push([data.object_count]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  
}

Answer (score 0):

When you use JSON.stringify(), it will return a string.  It looks like you want to have an object, not a string.

Try using this instead of your for loop:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data).map(function(key){ return key + ':' + data[key]});
```

Comment: I just tried to use it and keep getting a syntax error on that line.      function pullJSON(data) {
 var url="https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/subcategories/?          event_status=live&token=xxxxxxxxxx&page_count=4"; 
  
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
 var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
 
 
 var keys = Object.keys(data).map(key => key + ':' + data[key]);
 
}

Comment: What is the syntax error?  The only thing I think it could be is that I'm using an arrow function; you could replace it with a es5 function

Comment: I think that is it. I am using google scripts, so can i use the == instead. When i did that it removed the error but now i get an error that says key is not defined.

Comment: I've updated the code to use an es5 function instead of an arrow function

Comment: Thank. you Rob - that worked. I just have one more question. I don't know if i need to submit another question, if so let me know. But i just need to know how to push the data out so i can see the results in Logger.log().

Comment: Given you want to log keys, and keys is an array; assuming Logger.log takes a string, its just a matter of converting the array to a string.  You can do this with either JSON.stringify(keys) or keys.join(',') for a comma separated list.

Comment: I just want want all the field under subcategories.                                       {
    "pagination": {
        "object_count": 185, 
        "page_number": 1, 
        "page_size": 50, 
        "page_count": 4, 
        "continuation": "eyJwYWdlIjogMn0"
    }, 
     "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/subcategories/1001/", 
            "id": "1001", 
            "name": "Startups & Small Business", 
            "parent_category": {
                "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/101/", 
                 }
        }, 
        {

Comment: Instead of Object.keys(data) use Object.keys(data.subcategories)